# JOIN query ON column alias

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query which has a column alias created with a CASE statement, and I am trying to JOIN a subquery onto this.  I have managed to do so using OR statements in the JOIN, however the CASE statement has a default if the columns contain NULL, and I am not sure how to JOIN the data in this case.

The DDL statements of the tables of relevance is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `registration` (
  `registration_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'The primary identifier for a registration.',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The registration_type.type of this registration.',
  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The id of the entity this registration is associated with.',
  `entity_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type of the entity this registration is associated with.',
  `anon_mail` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Anonymous registrant’s e-mail address.',
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'How many spaces this registration should use towards the total capacity for this event.',
  `user_uid` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The uid of the user associated with this registration.',
  `author_uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The uid of the user who created this registration.',
  `state` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The registration_state.name of this registration.',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The Unix timestamp when the registration was created.',
  `updated` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The Unix timestamp when the registration was most recently saved.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`registration_id`),
  KEY `registration_updated` (`updated`),
  KEY `registration_created` (`created`),
  KEY `registration_type` (`type`(4)),
  KEY `registration_state` (`state`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61824 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='The base table for registration module.';

--

CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_reg_programme` (
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_reg_programme_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_reg_programme_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  KEY `field_reg_programme_format` (`field_reg_programme_format`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 178 (field_reg_programme)';

--

CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_programme` (
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_programme_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_programme_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  KEY `field_programme_format` (`field_programme_format`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 180 (field_programme)';
```

This is the query code I have tried so far:

```
SELECT
(CASE 
    WHEN prog.field_reg_programme_value IS NULL AND prof_prog.field_programme_value IS NULL THEN 'unknown'  
    WHEN prog.field_reg_programme_value IS NULL THEN prof_prog.field_programme_value
    WHEN prof_prog.field_programme_value IS NULL THEN prog.field_reg_programme_value
    ELSE 'unknown'
END) AS programme,
COUNT(r.registration_id) AS total,
COUNT(DISTINCT(r.user_uid)) AS 'distinct',
recurring.users AS 'recurring'

FROM
registration r
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_reg_programme prog ON r.registration_id = prog.entity_id
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_programme prof_prog ON r.user_uid = prof_prog.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(r.user_uid)) AS users, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN prog.field_reg_programme_value IS NULL AND prof_prog.field_programme_value IS NULL THEN 'unknown'  
        WHEN prog.field_reg_programme_value IS NULL THEN prof_prog.field_programme_value
        WHEN prof_prog.field_programme_value IS NULL THEN prog.field_reg_programme_value
        ELSE 'unknown'
    END) AS programme2
    FROM registration r
    LEFT JOIN field_data_field_reg_programme prog ON r.registration_id = prog.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN field_data_field_programme prof_prog ON r.user_uid = prof_prog.entity_id 
    WHERE r.state != 'system_cancellation' OR r.state != 'canceled'
    GROUP BY programme2
    HAVING COUNT(r.user_uid) > 2
) recurring ON (prog.field_reg_programme_value = recurring.programme2 OR prof_prog.field_programme_value = recurring.programme2)

WHERE r.state != 'system_cancellation' OR r.state != 'canceled'
GROUP BY programme, recurring.users
```

The output from this is:

```
programme   | total | distinct | recurring
------------+-------+----------+----------
programme1  |  20   |    12    |     4  
programme2  |  24   |    16    |     6    
programme3  |  30   |    19    |     5    
unknown     |   5   |     3    |    NULL
```

I know that the subquery has the unknown recurring number, it is just how to join it to the main table.

Example data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Em8U_jNY6HdVXBhHIeDxZ868BTM1Skkn).

Comment: I gave you a +1 for a pretty impressive first question for the tables &c. However, why don't you include the sample data in the question and then tell us the result you want and what logic you used to get that result? Your mistake, and why your question got closed, was you provided the output from your (large) query, but not the desired result!

Comment: "Prefix" indexing is virtually useless -- simply index the whole `registration_type`.  Is this inconsistency deliberate or a mistake:  `COUNT(DISTINCT(r.user_uid))` vs `COUNT(r.user_uid)`?